# 'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Laravel 8 new installation

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I have installed a new Laravel 8 application, and then I ran...

```
npm install
```

Afterward, I ran...

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following error.

> 'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>
> ```
> > @ dev E:\wamp64\www\Laravel8Projects\Laravel_Livewire_JetStream_Projects\jetstream_blog
> > npm run development
>
>
> > @ development E:\wamp64\www\Laravel8Projects\Laravel_Livewire_JetStream_Projects\jetstream_blog
> > mix
>
> 'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm
> ERR! @ development: `mix` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the @ development script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
> problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-18T17_03_24_944Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run
> development` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @
> dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-18T17_03_24_980Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Likely you need to install the latest version of Laravel Mix.

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 29):

**It will happen when your cache holds previous files.Clear the cache and install the npm again**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then:

```
npm install

npm fix audit
```

then:

```
npm run development
```

Comment: It is `npm audit fix` not `npm fix audit`

Answer (score 2):

my problem was solved by following these steps

```
 npm install --g laravel-mix

npm install --g webpack-cli
```

Comment: Installing webpack globally is not recommended https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#global-installation. `Note that this is [webpack global installation] not a recommended practice. Installing globally locks you down to a specific version of webpack and could fail in projects that use a different version`

Comment: I resolved installing laravel-mix globally. Probably you should remove the 3rd line anyway

Answer (score 0):

First delete node_modules directory and run below command one be one

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install

npm install --g laravel-mix

npm install --g webpack-cli

npm run development
```

Answer (score -1):

**NPM INSTALL**
it will repair it
It hapenned because you have some stuff installed after previous NMP I

So, in any strange situation - NPM INSTALL again)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

package.json requires you to run mix-watch command but it doesnt work

a simple fix that worked for me is running npm run watch it worked for me laravel 8 project

Answer (score -5):

If you are a windows user try this :

```
C:\Users{{your-username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

then :

```
npm cache verify
```