# npm run dev command not working Laravel 8 + vue js 3 project

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-8, laravel-mix

working with Laravel 8 and installed vue js 3 with the project as well and running laravel project with `php artisan serve` command as well. but when I tryed to start vue js for running vite with `npm run dev` got following error messages in the console

```
'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Modaya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-17T12_24_06_646Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

how could I fix this problem?

I need good solutions here

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^3.2.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.47"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `mix` command not found - what is `mix` when i runned `dev`?

> 'mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

You have declared a `dev` command in your `package.json` file, which, when invoked as `npm run dev`, runs the associated commands. In this case, the code might be:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
  }
}
```

1. call `dev` with `npm run dev` (you runned it)
2. call `development` by `dev` (automated by associated command)
3. call `mix` by `development` (automated by associated command)
4. Get error: `mix` not found (error message on your console)

#### How to can add `mix` command to project?

So, running `npm run dev` actually starts the same thing as if you entered `mix` in the console. However, the `mix` command does not exist. This is because you have not installed the `laravel-mix` package.

#### **`npm install laravel-mix@latest --save-dev`**

**IMPORTANT**: Remember that just because the dependency name is listed in the package.json file doesn't mean that you have actually installed it! You can easily check this by running the `npm install` command!

---

Same problem: ['mix' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Laravel 8 new installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779378/mix-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-laravel-8-new-inst)

Comment: i install npm again now when i run `npm run dev` got following messages here `1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 1 warning`

Comment: Read here for your new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083968/1-warning-in-child-compilations-use-stats-children-true-resp-stats-child

Comment: okay sir your 1st and second comments solved my problem